# How remove &#xd; from ciphervalue on cxf

Tags: soap, cxf

How remove "&#xd" from ciphervalue in CXF interceptor?

d00K/eqS/9UU6WsB1/TISj+rLWRf1HI0yDu4xA/00/fQa8w0xN+LKz+rCB87V3dleH67UigjRiMc&#xd

Thanks!

Comment: In debug i see the value of out message, in all lines have &#13 

Nxb1/fW3YzOC87iAkDAhO66kmyKhmop6Kmol7L7rnX7lM85xmKNBsZ7CyoEwffXhumWaxGGEkn79&#13;
1MGz+oH8SiNH6xb60AX81eKMSXwveuQUvyoHtZmlUf84XxKqdeRAOrxK6OL/et/97ruBAhr21nI5&#13;
sQf/7icheAkSoZXFRrnJ0h9sLidc5EsZI8yfioF5axE3m7sQXjWEoG2bs+EfOKYHghC0E3jj4mp8&#13;